# Jupyter kernel keeps dying

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I am trying to load the images from my dataset. The images are in tif format and 256X256 pixels. My kernel dies when I run the following code:

```
filelist = glob("train/im/*.tif")
mask_list = glob("train/msk/*.tif")

input_images = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname).resize((128,128), resample=0)) for fname in filelist])
target_masks = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname).resize((128,128), resample=0)) for fname in mask_list])
```

Comment: Perhaps your computer get out of memory. Check the memory status when running the program.

Answer (score 0):

As probably correctly pointed out in the comment you run out of memory and this is the reason why the kernel does.

To handle data on a disk that is larger than your RAM you should use generators and `yield` keyword, in your case:

```
def generator(filelist, masklist):
    for file, mask in zip(filelist, masklist):
        yield np.asarray(Image.open(file)), np.asarray(Image.open(mask))
```

If you are working with PyTorch check out [datasets & dataloaders](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html) to get a better performance.